# How to make browser ignore html tags

Tags: html

i have created a site where users can make an account by typing in a username and password if i make an account and type `<h1> dan</h1>` as my username the username will show up on the site as a header. this can lead to loads of abuse if someone was to use perhaps an img src or a load of line breaks. how do i make the browser ignore the html tags so if i was to type `<h1> dan</h1>`that it would either get rid of the html or just print out the html as regular text.

Comment: What are you running on? ASP.NET, JSP, PHP etc.? Usually it's *"best"* to take care of this on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Various answers for some programming languages have already been given. You might want to read about the underlying techniques (as well as other common threats in web development) on http://www.owasp.org/.

Welcome to the world of security issues in web development

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is called input validation.  A lot of work has already been done on this subject, and it is never a good idea to start doing this from scratch.  The most important thing to remember is that input validation has to be done on the server side, as client side can easily be manipulated.

[ESAPI](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet) (by OWASP) is an open source library for web security which amongst other things lets you do Input Validation, it has implementations in many languages including PHP and Java.  If you're interested in using ESAPI with Java you can take a look at [my blog](http://amirzucker.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/creating-an-online-service-dont-start-from-scratch/) where I use ESAPI for input validation, if you're using another language there are examples for those on the web.

Answer (score 0):

simply output the username using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

> The translations performed are:
>
> - '&' (ampersand) becomes '`&amp;`'
> - '"' (double quote) becomes '`&quot;`' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
> - "'" (single quote) becomes '`&#039;`' (or `&apos;`) only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
> - '<' (less than) becomes '`&lt;`'
> - '>' (greater than) becomes '`&gt;`'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can clean html tags when you are creating the user on you server side code.

Also:
I think that is a must clean the values coming from the client side in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Either you'll have to get rid off all html tags, or - much simpler - replace all `<` and `>` characters with their html-encodings, `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in the browser, you have to do this in your backend.

1. Identify allowed characters in username,password, whatever value you ask for
2. When the form is submitted -> validate the input against your previously defined pattern (on the server)
3. Escape/Encode your data before it is send to the client (browser), i.e. so that `<h1> dan</h1>` would become `&lt;h1glt; dan&lt;/h1&gt;`
4. Make yourself confident with some security concerns and how to avoid them like sql injection or crosssite scripting